# What are the biggest determinants for the SEC to successfully enforce market discipline?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, sec

While not a smoking gun, a single New Jersey Deli with four-figure revenue that succeeded in floating 8 million shares and eventually reached a market cap of over a hundred million dollars seems to be enough of a red flag for the likes of hedge fund manager Einhorn. As [this article](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/04/19/hometown-international-nj-deli-linked-legal-problems.html) points out, a major reason this company has come under greater scrutiny stems from the managers sarcastic remarks. [The latest](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/04/22/hometown-international-stock-100m-nj-deli-delisted-disclosure-irregularities.html) in the story suggests the firm may face delisting.

Though anecdotal, Hometown International joins a growing list of high profile instances of how the SEC has struggled to protect shareholder capital. Though not directly comparable, the regulator's inability to act on a material amount of evidence in the form of letters and reports from within the industry regarding Madoff's operations suggests it was not easy to build/act on a strong case even in the face of blatant market abuse. In a recent interview, [Harvey Pitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Pitt) had this to say:

> It is clear that there were letters, and it is also clear that the SEC
> did look at [Madoff]. What is not clear is why the SEC was unable to
> conclude that he was conducting the Ponzi Scheme we now know he was
> conducting.

Presumably, the regulator would want to enforce greater discipline in these situations to avoid a collapse in investor confidence. However, in both of the cases above, it was the industry that unveiled the malfeasance.

### Question

Is this as simple as the regulator being understaffed / underfunded or is the degree of certainty needed for a conviction unrealistically high?

Comment: This excellent question would be suited to the economics site.  Or perhaps politics or even the quants site.